# Bi-LSTM: How to handle unigram and bigrams for a NLP classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a chinese text and I use a Bi-LSTM to predict if each character of the text belongs to one of these classes:

B (if the charatcer is at the beginning of the word), 
I (if it is inside the word), 
E (if it is at the end of the word)
S (if it is a single character).

For doing this, I have taken each character of the text and I have built a dictionary, thanks to this I was able to transform the sequence of characters into a sequences of numbers that I give to my network (after the phase of padding), for example:

dictionary={t:1, h:2, e:3, p:4, n:5}
The pen -> 123 435 -> network -> BIE BIE

Everything is ok if I'm working with unigram. However, my network should read also bigrams. How should I handle bigrams? I don't have specific labels for bigrams. (Maybe, my network for each bigram should gives two labels? It doesn't make sense to me)